# Filter ArrayList of HashMap based on date values

Tags: java, logic

Need to filter duplicates values by id keeping the record with latest timestamp.

Below is the code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> sampleMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();      
sampleMap.put("Name", "Ronaldo");
sampleMap.put("Playerid", "11");
sampleMap.put("Date", "2020-05-01T08:35:42-04:00");

HashMap<String, Object> sampleMap1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();     
sampleMap1.put("Name", "Messi");
sampleMap1.put("Playerid", "12");
sampleMap1.put("Date", "2020-06-01T08:35:42-04:00");

HashMap<String, Object> sampleMap2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();     
sampleMap2.put("Name", "Messi");
sampleMap2.put("Playerid", "12");
sampleMap2.put("Date", "2020-05-01T08:35:42-04:00");

ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> fMap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

fMap.add(sampleMap);
fMap.add(sampleMap1);
fMap.add(sampleMap2);
```

Expected Result :

```
fmap[sampleMap, sampleMap1]
```

Final Output should have only sampleMap, sampleMap1 because sampleMap1 and sampleMap2 have same playerId but date for sampleMap1 is latest hence it should be there not sampleMap2.

Couldn't find logic to solve this case. Please help me out

Comment: Seems you're asking 2 questions: 1) How to filter duplicates by ID, keeping the record with latest timestamp, and 2) How to sort the list by timestamp. --- If so, you should ask those as two separate questions. If not so, then edit the question and clarify what you're asking. --- *Hint:* Finding the *latest* is not a *sorting* operation, it's a *filtering* operation.

Comment: Edited. My question is first one How to filter duplicates by ID, keeping the record with latest timestamp

Comment: Then the word "sort" should be nowhere to be found with this question. You haven't fixed that yet.

Comment: Fixed it now ...

Comment: Build a `Map` keyed by `Playerid`, and only replace existing entries if the new data is newer.

Comment: Side note: Those maps look like they'd better be replaced by instances of proper classes, e.g. `Player`. Then your `fMap` could become a `Map<String, Player>` with the key being the player id (`fMap` even already implies you're dealing with a map rather than a list). Maybe `Player` would even have a set/list of dates depending on what those represent.

Comment: To add to @Thomas idea, why not use a `Set` instead of `List`? You can avoid duplicates by implementing `equals()` in your `Player` class such that the equality is checked based on parameters other than the `Date`. The inherent assumption here is that `Date` is a field that is always going to increment and not going backwards!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort a list of maps. You could use the functions of Java 8, namely Stream API. The comparator often uses for sort. You could choose which fields you want to sort by Comparator.comparing(map ->map.get("field")). To remove duplicate value the Stream API represents the distinct() function.

Your list of players could be sorted like this:

```
    fMap.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(map -> Integer.parseInt((String)map.get("Playerid")))
                          .thenComparing(map -> LocalDate.parse((String)map.get("Date"), 
                                                                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",Locale.ENGLISH))))
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: But you need to edit DataTimeFormatter for your option, please.

Comment: @Thomas, Thx for the explanation. The next time I'm being careful in writing a response.

Comment: Well, there doesn't have to be a next time - you could practice it right now ;)

Comment: @Thomas I took into account your remark and was fixed errors.

Comment: One note: instead of using `sorted()` twice you might want to combine comparators using `Comparator.thenComparing()` etc. That would make it easier to understand.